# Get specific pixel from texture in material node

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a cel-shading material with nodes in Blender Render and a texture with the diffuse colors.

I want to use the empty space of the texture to specify accent colors for the material. For example, the shadow color, the highlight color, the rim light color. So instead of RGB input node, I would get a specific texel in the empty space of the diffuse texture.

But there is something weird about the texture coordinates.

[image]

Shouldn't position (0,1) of the texture be the top-left pixel? I should return the light blue color but returned the darker blue in the bottom-middle of the texture. If I try (0,0), instead of yellow I get black.

What is happing here?

Comment: Instead of the combine RGB, use a vector mapping, with no input. Set it to "point" and tune the locations (X, Y) between -1 and +1 (excluded, so for instance practically between -0.99 and +0.99)

Comment: @lemon Oh, so texture space is -1 to 1! But I don't get why it doesn't repeat although the image mapping is set to do it.

Comment: It does repeat. And you can actually do it with a combine RGB. But it is less easy as RGB values have soft limits between 0 and 1. And effectively I do not know why it is -1 to 1...